# Tracking traffic from mobile devices' home screen in Google Analytics

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, google-analytics, apple-touch-icon

Does anyone know if it's possible to track website traffic coming specifically from a home screen icon on an Apple device?

E.g. when I specify the following HTML I can obviously control the image that appears when the user adds a shortcut on their homescreen:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="touch-icon-ipad.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">
<etc, etc>
```

[image]

I'd like to know how many people are launching from their homescreen i.e. pressing the orange button in the above example. I don't think it's possible, but I was wondering if anyone had a trick up their sleeves?

TIA ♥

Answer (score 2):

`navigator.standalone` 
Returns a boolean indicating whether the browser is running in standalone mode. Available on Apple's iOS Safari only.

```
if (window.navigator.standalone) {
  // From home screen
}
```

From [Safari Web Content Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW2):

> You can determine whether a webpage is displaying in standalone mode
>   using the `window.navigator.standalone` read-only Boolean JavaScript
>   property. For more on standalone mode, see apple-mobile-web-app-capable.

Comment: [Safari HTML Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html): You can determine whether a webpage is displayed in full-screen mode using the `window.navigator.standalone` read-only Boolean JavaScript property.